# Specifying covariance structure for unbalanced data in gls() and lme()

Tags: panel-data, generalized-least-squares

I'm wondering if we could use `gls` for unbalanced longitudinal data (in the sense that every group has different number of measurements and the measurement timepoints are also different). When I try to use `corr=corSymm(form= ~ age|id)` to specify the unstructured covariance in gls(),i.e.:

```r
gls(ht ~ baseage + age_normed, data=data, 
    corr=corSymm(form= ~ age_normed|id), method='ML')
```

it returns the error:

```r
Error in Initialize.corSymm(X[[i]], ...) : 
   unique values of the covariate for "corSymm" objects must be a sequence 
   of consecutive integers
```

I encountered a similar problem for `lme()`, but it seems like we can circumvent this by specifying the random effect to be `~1+age|id`, and it's naturally associated with unstructured covariance:

```r
lme(ht ~ age_normed + I(age_normed^2) + baseage, 
    random= ~ 1+age_normed | id, data=data, method="ML")
```

Still, my question is if we can use `gls()` for unbalanced longitudinal data?

Comment: In your gls, age_normed should have values 1,2,3,... etc. Whole positive numbers are required.  

By the way, in general I would not expect un unstructured (co)variance matrix with the lme you mentioned. That would only be true for 2 fixed occasions, but then you may experience convergence problems.

Comment: Thank you! That's so true, because my second line of code indeed cannot converge (I guess the default is form=~1|id ? ). currently my age_normed looks like 7.41,9.45, etc., which is the exact measurement time for each subject. In this case, I can pass the argument "form=~age_normed | id" successfully to AR(1), so I'm wondering if this error mentioned only occurs for CorSymm? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, I checked both R documentation, it says both corSymm and corAR should have integer values, but corCAR allows non-integer values. Thank you for leading me onto the right way!

Comment: Hi George, forgot to mention that for unstructured gls with heterogeneous variances you should also add a weight= to the script, as in:   
  
correlation =  corSymm(form = ~ occasion |id), weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | occasion) )   

 if occasion is numerical, valued 1, 2, 3 etc.